# What is the difference between examining for linear independence and span when a matrix is in REF / RREF?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've seen theoretical examples that differentiate between the definitions of each and believe I understand the two concepts in theory, but I'm not sure how these actually appear differently when using Gaussian / Gauss-Jordan elimination. I've been told that if it is successfully placed in RREF and has rank equal to the number of rows in the original representation, then it is a spanning set, but wouldn't this also mean that it is linearly independent? I'm aware that the concepts are not mutually inclusive, but the aforementioned test seems to imply they are.

In short, an explanation of how to separately test for each using Gaussian / Gauss-Jordan elimination, where the test is not inclusive of both, would likely provide sufficient clarification for me.

Appreciate it!

Edit: I believe I have arrived at an answer. Would it be correct to say that the RREF matrix represents a spanning set iff rank = the number of rows, and is linearly independent iff rank = the number of columns? Apologies for the premature question if my new understanding is correct!

Follow-Up Edit: It appears as though I've been unclear. I'll provide a concrete example below.

Take this vector set:

[Vector set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9pBR.png)

This vector set can be represented as the following matrix:

1 -1 -3

1  1  5

2  1  6

-1  0  -1

Placing it into RREF, I get

1  0  1

0  1  4

0  0  0

0  0  0

What I'm unclear on is how this can be used to determine whether or not the vector set is a spanning set, and whether or not it is linearly independent.

My new understanding is that if the rank (as easily determined by the new RREF) is = to the number of rows in the original representation (i.e there are no zero rows in RREF) then it is a spanning set, and if the rank is = to the number of columns in the original representation then it is linearly independent.

(So by my new understanding, it can be stated that it is neither a spanning set nor linearly independent, because the rank = 2, which is less than the number of rows (4, for the spanning set test) and less than the number of columns (3, for the linear independence test)

Is this correct, completely off, or not nuanced enough?

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what you are asking,  "Linear independence" and "span" are properties of a set of vectors in a vector space, not matrices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ashamed I managed to keep overlooking this earlier.  This tidbit from my textbook fully answers my original question and provides extra info, for those struggling to find the same info:

[Theorem That Answers My Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv1KT.png)

Answer (score 0):

A set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, v_n\}$ in a given vector space, V, "spans" that space if every vector in that space can be written as a "linear combination" of the vectors in the space.  That is, if $v\in V$ then there exist numbers, $C_1, C_2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, C_n$, such that $v= C_1v_1+ C_2v_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ C_nv_n$.

A set of vectors, $\{v_1, v_2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, v_n\}$, is "independent" if whenever $C_1v_1+ C_2v_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ C_nv_n= 0$ then $C_1= C_2= \cdot\cdot\cdot= C_n= 0$.  Another way of saying that is that there is only **one** way to write a given vector as a linear combination of the vectors $\{v_1, v_2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, v_n\}$.

No, they are not at all the same. In one sense "spanning set" and "independent" are opposites.  A set containing a single non-zero vector is independent (it should be clear that if a set contains the 0 vector then it is not independent).  Any subset of an independent set is also independent but a "super set" (a set with this set as a subset) may not span the set.  The set containing all the vectors in a space obviously spans the space is not "independent".

You could start with an independent set of vectors (say a single non-zero vector) and add independent vectors until there are no more vectors independent of the vectors in the set- the resulting set necessarily spans the space.

Or start with a set of vectors that spans the vector space (say the entire space) and **remove** vectors that are linear combinations of the others until there are no more- the resulting set is necessarily independent.

If there exist a set of vectors that both spans the space and is independent, it is a "basis" for the vector space- every vector in the space can be written, in **one and only one way**, as a linear combination of vectors in the basis.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but like I stated; I'm familiar with the theory in terms of stating it in English and what each mean by definition.  I'm just unsure how one could "test" for each using Gaussian / Gauss-Jordan elimination. I'll append some more to my original question to be more clear.